# is there any way to get into my nokia (3120 classic) without using nokia's software

Tags: sms, text-messaging

i have some important information in my sent messages but i left it too long and it's way over-full and playing up. I have written a script to interpret the .vmg files which works quite well, i just need to get them onto my computer.

the phone itself refuses to recognize their existence at all, Nokia PC suite loads some of them but misses a lot (there were over 6000 in there but only about 4000 show up in PC suite)

Nokia Ovi seems even worse, and it wants me to Sync it which i'm worried will delete the ones not on the computer already (most of them).

i tried getting into it via windows explorer but only the gallery folder is visible.

i can't seem to locate it via the command line, is there a way to get to it from the command line? (i'm running windows 7, i have a linux virtual machine but i don't think the free versionof virtual box has USB support)

Answer (score 2):

[gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/downloads.shtml) might work.

It has Linux and Windows versions.

VirtualBox doesn't support USB in the open source version, but there is a free-as-in-beer closed source version that does.  See their [editions page](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions) for details.

Comment: you sure it does text messages? it says it sends and receives but doesn't mention copying them onto my computer?

Comment: The docs show a `--getsms` option.  http://wiki.gnokii.org/index.php/SMS_options